# jQuery plugin returning its init function rather than the result of calling the plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, snackbar

I'm working with the [snackbarjs](https://github.com/FezVrasta/snackbarjs) jQuery plugin. I'm calling it in my Django template like so:

```
<script>
    var options = {
        content: "Testing some Some snackbar text",
        // style: "toast", 
        timeout: 0,
        //htmlAllowed: true 
    };
    var test = $.snackbar(options);
    console.log('test is: ');
    console.log(test);
</script>
```

I'm requiring the plugin using Browserify:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('snackbarjs');
```

Right now, the output of my `test` variable is

```
jQuery.fn.init[1]
```

...which I believe is the result of initializing snackbarjs itself. It should be returning the HTML of the Snackbar.

When I run the same snackbar initialization code from the browser console after the page has loaded, it runs fine, and `test` returns the `<div>` of the snackbar I'm trying to load.

How can I get the snackbar jQuery plugin to work inside my template, and what's going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript function was calling before the DOM was ready. The plugin appends the div it produces to the end of the DOM, and by calling it while the DOM was still painting, I suspect this overwrites the contents of that `<div>`.

I wrapped the call to the jQuery plugin in `$(document).ready` and it works fine.